# break; statement in PHP function

Tags: php

I'm reading through code I've just been assigned, and amid many `case` statements is a single, lone `break;`.  It's not wrapped in any `switch` statements.  It's just there, and doesn't seem to have any purpose.  I'm new to PHP, is this some advanced code use, or just leftover code?

Here's the code:

```
function foo() {
...many for/switch statements (all with closing brackets)...
    break;
...other code....
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Like I said, it's there.  Nothing around it.  Added code anyway.

Comment: Could you post the WHOLE code?

Comment: So what happens if you remove it, god forbid!

Comment: So this isn't some new use of `break;` that I haven't heard of?

Comment: If you put a break outside a looping structure (and for these purposes `switch` counts as a loop) you get [this error](http://codepad.org/4P7fdnAo): `Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level on line x` - if you don't get an error, there is a loop that you haven't spotted. Or that bit of code is never reached and is therefore redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this test code:

```
function testing() {
    echo('begin...<br>');
    break;
    echo('end.<br>');
}

testing();
```

I get as output (PHP 5.3.10 on Windows):

```
begin...
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in E:\Dev\Webstore Dev\test.php on line xx
```

Which means that if you are not getting a fatal error, then it is most likely contained in some structure that it wants to break out of or, as DaveRandom pointed out, that line is never reached.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question I was asking.  No error, so there was a case statement it was `break;`ing, but the code was terribly formatted so that it lead both me and Notepad++ to believe there were closing statements.  Upon closer inspection, this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in a loop? If so, it will stop the loop from looping.

Comment: Then it doesn't do anything. Delete it and see if your code still functions the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `switch` expression, then know that switch usualy contains `break;` expressions, like so:

```
switch($conditions) {
    case $case1 :
        //do something and finish
        break;
    case $case2 :
        // do something else and finish
        break;
    case $case3 :
        //do something elser and continue with next case
    case $case4 :
        //finally do something else and finish
        break;
    default:
        //if no case is matched, then do something here...
}
```

That's why there is a `break` present...

It also could be present in a loop (`while`, `for`, `foreach` or `do-while`) to stop further looping...